# numpy einsum to get axes permutation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transpose, numpy-einsum

What I understood in the documentation of ‘np.einsum‘ is that a permutation string, would give a permutation of the axis in a vector. This is confirmed by the following experiment:

```
>>> M = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> M.shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> np.einsum('ijk', M).shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> np.einsum('ikj', M).shape
(2, 4, 3)
>>> np.einsum('jik', M).shape
(3, 2, 4)
```

But this I cannot understand:

```
>>> np.einsum('kij', M).shape
(3, 4, 2)
```

I would expect (4, 2, 3) instead... What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the output signature is not specified (i.e. there's no `'->'` in the subscripts string), `einsum` will create it by taking the letters it's been given and arranging them in alphabetical order.

This means that

```
np.einsum('kij', M)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
np.einsum('kij->ijk', M)
```

So writing `'kij'` labels the axes of the *input* matrix, not the output matrix, and this leads to the permutation of the axes that you observed.

This point isn't made explicit in the documentation, but can be seen commented in the [C source code for `einsum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c852f5999c79fa7b7799756e824dcc0270e58913/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#l2689):

```
/*
 * If there is no output signature, create one using each label
 * that appeared once, in alphabetical order
 */
```

To ensure the axes of `M` are permuted in the intended order, it may be necessary to give `einsum` the labeling for both the input and output matrices:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijk->kij', M).shape
(4, 2, 3)
```